# Name new sheet according to cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to combine two scripts here:

1) Get a cell value in a specific sheet

```
function getval() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('master'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 4).activate();
};
```

2) Create a new sheet and rename it according to cell value

```
spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('');
```

The second step is where I struggle. How can I use the results of the getval function as a variable to place inside setName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function insertAndNameNewSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('master');
  var name=sh.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 4).getValue();//2 rows down and 4 columns to the right
  ss.insertSheet(name,1);
}
```

[insertSheet(name,index)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer))

[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Returns an error message saying spreadsheet is not defined on line 5..

Comment: Try it again.  I left an undefined variable in there when I renamed the variables.

Comment: I simplified my initial script and threw in some of the elements you mentioned. Works now. Thank you for your time.